# Direct Printing from Webpage

Tags: javascript, browser, web-applications

Is it possible to issue a print command directly from a webpage without having to use the `Ctrl` + `P` keyboard combination. I heard from somewhere (though I don't exactly remember) that JavaScript cannot directly access the printer for you to issue a direct print without the keyboard combination.

Comment: Use [window.print()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp). It will open up print dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Use the print API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.print();">print the page</a>
```